# Hive Query with multiple joins not executing

Tags: join, hive, aggregate

I wrote a Hive query to compute 33 and 66 percentile on multiple columns of a table that contains integer values (including 0).

Just to filter outliers, I added the filter >0 before computing percentile.

I have 46 columns and I calculate 33 and 66 percentile on each column, with the >0 filter on column.

Then I join these results to get a table with 33 and 66 percentiles of these columns.

My issue is that the query doesn't execute. I tried executing with 2 columns and it works fine but doesn't work on this huge number of joins. Can someone suggest an alternate way.

Data looks like this:

```
    C1| C2| C3
 ---------------
    0 | 2 | 3
    1 | 0 | 2
    2 | 0 | 0
```

> for C1, the data will be [1,2];  for C2 -> [2];   for  C3 -> [3,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not do that

just use percentile udf of hive

```
select percentile(C1,0.33),.....,percentile(C46,0.33) from table
UNION ALL
select percentile(C1,0.66),.....,percentile(C46,0.66) from table
```

This gives you a table having 46 columns with first row indicating the 33rd percentile of each column and 2nd row indicating the 66th percentile of each column

or you can do

```
select percentile(C1,0.33),.....,percentile(C46,0.33) , percentile(C1,0.66),.....,percentile(C46,0.66) from table
```

Comment: I understand that I can use aggregate functions on each column but the only challenge is to apply >0 on each column separately. So my query looks like:
select * from 
(
   ( select percentile(C1,0.33),
    select percentile(C1,0.66) from table where C1>0) c1,
   (  select percentile(C2,0.33),
    select percentile(C2,0.66) from table where C2>0) c2,
    .........
)
And with this high number of joins, the query does not execute